# Posicionar uma imagem corretamente dentro de uma div

Tags: html, css

Bom dia, estou tentando solucionar um problema: tenho uma div circular e quando insiro uma imagem ela fica cortada:

html

```
<div class="side-menu-user-info">
    <div class="side-menu-user-photo">

    </div>        
</div>
```

css

```
.side-menu-user-info{
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  height: 190px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(155, 158, 162);
  position: relative;
}

.side-menu-user-photo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px;
  background-image: url("user-logo.png")
}
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Se te interessar eu resolvi de uma forma um pouco diferente usando `flexbox` do css, veja o exemplo.

```css
.side-menu-user-info{
      background: #FFF;
      display: block;
      height: 190px;
      border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(155, 158, 162);
      position: relative;
    }

.side-menu-user-photo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%
}
```

```html
    <div class="side-menu-user-info">
        <div class="side-menu-user-photo">
            <img src="http://pluspng.com/img-png/user-png-icon-male-user-icon-512.png">
        </div>        
    </div>
```

Comment: Otavio, exatamente o que eu precisava, mas quando tento utilizar a minha imagem ela sobrepõe a div e fica por cima!

Comment: Como você esta fazendo? somente alterou a imagem dentro da tag?

Comment: Exato, utilizei exatamente da sua forma, mas dentro da sua tag <img> eu coloquei a minha imagem

Comment: cria um jsfidlle e me manda para ver oq ocorre

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/sp7czfx2/1/#      
com a tua imagem, vou responder na minha pergunta como fica pois nao consigo enviar aqui

Answer (score 2):

Já que a sua imagem está como `background` vc pode tratar isso apenas com `background-size` e `background-position`. Não precisa colocar uma tag `<img>` caso queira, já que no seu código vc usa a imagem como `backgound`. Apesar disso por usar o `width` em `%` acaba ficando deformado, não sei se é isso que vc quer...

```css
.side-menu-user-info{
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  height: 190px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgb(155, 158, 162);
  position: relative;
}
    
.side-menu-user-photo {
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 40%;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 10px;
  background-image: url("https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/61/61205.png");
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="side-menu-user-info">
    <div class="side-menu-user-photo">

    </div>        
</div>
```

Comment: Hugo, obrigado pela informação! Tbm me ajudou bastante

Comment: @FernandoMunhoz legal que ajudou, se quiser continuar usado a img como background esse código resolve. E se vc quiser evitar a deformação na imagem coloque ela com a altura = largura... (width e height com o mesmo valor)

Comment: Hugo, fiz uma adaptação, como futuramente essa imagem vai ser alterada de acordo com a opção do usuário eu deveria ter o <img> dentro do meu html e não background no css e quando coloco a img direto no html ele fica imenso

Comment: @FernandoMunhoz entendi, como no seu código estava como background eu responde com background. Se quiser com imagem a outra resposta te atende acredito